# Proof using properties of integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $|f(x)| \le M$, then $\displaystyle \left|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right| \le M(b-a)$.

Answer (score 2):

For any partition $\{a=x_0,x_1,...,x_n=b\}$ you have that the corresponding Riemman sum is: $$ 
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$
Here I use the right end point (you should have seen a theorem that states that doesnt matter which point you pick, if the function is integrable then the answer in the limit will be the same). $$ 
|\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n M x_i-x_{i-1}=M(b-a)$$
Since this holds for an arbitrary partition, then taking supremum over all partitions, which yields $\int_a^b f$ will also be less or equal to $M(b-a)$

Comment: Okay that makes sense thank you! So would I also use that to prove that the absolute value of the integral f(x) from a to b is less than or equal to the integral from a to b of the absolute value of f(x) ?

Comment: well if you haven't proved that in class then yeah, but that is usually done in class.

Comment: Check of a theorem that says if $f\leq g$ in $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f\leq \int_a^b g$.

Comment: No we have not done it in class yet unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx \right|\leq \int_{a}^b |f(x)|dx\leq \int_{a}^{b}Mdx=M\int_a^bdx=M(b-a),$$
where the first inequality is for the follow property of integral: $|\int_a^b f|\leq \int_a^b|f|$ and the second inequality is for hypothesis: $|f(x)|\leq M$.